# Combining a base uri to an MVC action and controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, uri

I am developing an MVC application and I want to combine my Application url to a controller and action and instead of using string.Format etc i decided to get all fancy and use Uri functions like

```
Uri.TryCreate(baseUri, relativeUrl, out newUri)
```

Now my base uri is http:.//localhost/abc/web and my relative url is "NerdDinner/Invite"

now the new uri that is given out is  http:.//localhost/abc/NerdDinner/Invite

where as I am looking for  http:.//localhost/abc/Web/NerdDinner/Invite.

Please note adding a trailing '/' to the base url is not an idea that i am looking for which works btw.

Can someone help me with the same. Please note I dont have access to Url.Action etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be pithy, but if adding a trailing slash works, why is that not an acceptable solution?

Comment: Say if the baseuri contains the trailing / then my absolute uri will look like follows: http:.//localhost/abc/Web//NerdDinner/Invite. :O :|

hence I dont want to add it myself

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using *Url.Action(Action, Controller)* method?
e.g.

```
<%=Url.Action("Invite","NerdDinner")%>
```

Comment: aH!! I mentioned in the question. i cant access - Url.Action

Comment: Why don't you have access to Url.Action?